# Should we use overrides or a static constructor when overriding AutofacServiceHostFactory

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, net.tcp

We are running WCF services with net.tcp bindings in IIS 7.5, so we make use of non-HTTP activations and WAS Hosting.  We are have created a custom service host factory for each service, which is derived from AutofacServiceHostFactory

I was recently doing some maintenance on the services (switching to use NuGet packages upgrading to the latest versions, etc). I happened to notice that the [wiki article for WCF Integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration) recommends using an override of `CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)` and building up the container there before calling the base implementation.

Our ServiceHostFactories have been using a static constructor to do the same thing. I'm wondering if I should switch. Is there a reason a static constructor is a bad idea? If using the overrides, we need to override any of the other overloads for `CreateServiceHost()`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nothing? I was hoping the Autofac team would comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the recommendation has changed again to use the `AppStart.AppInitialize()` to register the dependencies and build the container in a protocol agnostic faction. That's what we're doing now.

[Autofac Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration)

[Referenced article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/11/511514.aspx)